# Diffing web.config is hard, any way to prevent IIS Manager from formatting Web.config differently than Visual Studio's format?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-manager

this drives me crazy.

Visual Studio does not format Web.config the same way than IIS Manager, which prevent easy diffing of different versions or the same file editing in both tools.

When Visual Studio edits a Web.config thru a wizard (like adding a reference) or when you click on Edit\Format Document (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D), Visual Studio formats the XML in a beautiful way.

Unfortunately, if you change a value in IIS, it will reformat it with a different style.

Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

no matter how ugly the xml is inside a file, when you open the file with visual studio press control k and then control d and it will format the XML for you instantly.

Comment: This is what I would like to prevent, I would like that when IIS change the web.config, that it get formated visual studio style so that the next commit is easy to diff in the future in one step. I do not want to open web.config, Ctrl+k Ctrl+D before each commit, it's too repetitive.